# Automatically testing an Android function that needs user authentication

Tags: android, security, authentication, testing

I am trying to require user authentication through Keyguard Manager for an Android app as part of a flow. This means that user must be authenticated to go through the flow. This is accomplished by starting a Keyguard Manager createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent generated activityForResult and receiving an activityResult from it.

I want to test that flow automatically. This causes a problem because my automated test isn't able to authenticate itself(i.e. enter swipe pattern or enter PIN). How can I get my test to automatically pass this to put the test environment into an authenticated state? Can I mock some function in the Keyguard Manager to automatically pass the authentication check?

[Keyguard Manager](http://Keyguard%20Manager%20createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent)

[createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: For a PIN, Ui Automator may work to automate entering the PIN.

Comment: I was hoping to have this work for all authentication types. Also I'm not sure this will work for Android because the tests don't generally use the screens but I'll try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was more abstraction. Previously I had been doing encrpytion and decryption through static methods. I switched to using an Encryptor and Decryptor object which had a field "userAuthenticationRequired", and using a Builder to set that field as part of building an encryptor. This allowed me to test authentication by passing in an Encryptor with userAuthenticationRequired when running the app, and without that field as false when testing the app.